# Extending instantiated objects by importing: Bad Idea?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I have list of many `City` objects, and at some point after their creation, they will be labelled, so a `Label` field will be set for each one.

I want to do this in a functional, stateless way, i.e. without setting a default and using `var`. I'm really just curious as to what the best practice is.

I've got this working example, but I feel pretty funny about it. Notice, in particular, that I'm `import`-ing the existing `City` objects, which happens when I call `City.addLabel(label)`.

```
case class LabelledCity(importCity: CityLike, label: Label) extends CityLike with Labelled 
{
  val cityState = importCity.cityState
  val income = importCity.income
}

case class City(string: String) extends CityLike {
  val split = string.split(" --- ")
  val cityState = split(0)
  val income = split(1).toInt
}

abstract class CityLike {
  def addLabel(l: Label): LabelledCity = { new LabelledCity(this, l) }
  val cityState: String
  val income: Int
}
```

**This all feels a little wrong, or like I'm missing something simple... am I?**

Answer (score 4):

Here is the immutable way to archive this (I have dropped class bodies for a sake of simplicity):

```
case class City(string: String, label: Option[String] = None)
val unknown = City("somestring")
// unknown: City = City(somestring,None)
val washington = unknown.copy(label = Some("Washington"))
// washington: City = City(somestring,Some(Washington))
```

Comment: Can always augment that with a `Lens` as well, if you want to get fancy.

Comment: Ah, of course... I knew about `copy`, but I was trying to use it inside the case class itself. Didn't think to use it on the instantiated objects.

Comment: I'm still curious: Is using a default set to `None` the preferred way to go here? I was basically trying to see if I could avoid setting defaults altogether.

Comment: it could be null or empty string (but None clearly indicates that there is no value yet), but yes, setting default value in some way for such solution is required. I mean it could be explicit (no default in constructor signature), but still default